# Array of html inputs

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have a html form, where user need to enter the name and address of their office. The number of offices are dynamic.

I want to add an **Add More** button, so that users can enter the details of any number of offices.

My question is, how can I create an array of inputs where new elements can be added and removed using JavaScript. Currently, I'm doing it using js clone method, but I want an array, so that input data can easily be validated and stored to database using Laravel.

What I'm currently doing..
This is my HTML form where users have to enter the address of their clinic or office. I've taken a hidden input field and increasing the value of that field whenever a new clinic is added, so that I can use loop for storing data.

```
<div class="inputs">
    <label><strong>Address</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="hidden" value="1" id="clinicCount" />
    <div id="addresscontainer">
        <div id="address">
            <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label><strong>Clinic 1</strong></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button id="deleteclinic" type="button" class="close deleteclinic" 
                    onclick="removeClinic(this)">&times;</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <textarea name="address1" placeholder="Enter Clinic Address" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <label class="text-muted" style="margin-top:10px">Coordinates (Click on map to get coordinates)</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control" id="latitude" type="text" name="latitude1" placeholder="Latitude" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control" id="longitude" type="text" name="longitude1" placeholder="Longitude" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-right">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="addclinic">Add More</button>
</div>
```

And my js code..

```
function numberClinic(){
    //alert('test');
    var i=0; 
    $('#addresscontainer > #address').each(function () { 
        i++;
        $(this).find("strong").html("Clinic " + i);
        $(this).find("textarea").attr('name','name'+i);
        $(this).find("#latitude").attr('name','latitude'+i);
        $(this).find("#longitude").attr('name','longitude'+i);
    });
}
$("#addclinic").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#addresscontainer").append($("#address").clone());
    numberClinic();
    $("#addresscontainer").find("div#address:last").find("input[name=latitude]").val('');
    $("#addresscontainer").find("div#address:last").find("input[name=longitude]").val('');

    $("#clinicCount").val(parseInt($("#clinicCount").val())+1);
});

function removeClinic(address){
    if($("#clinicCount").val()>1){
        $(address).parent('div').parent('div').parent('div').remove();
        $("#clinicCount").val(parseInt($("#clinicCount").val())-1);
    }
    numberClinic();
}
```

This way, I think I can store the data to the database but can't validate the data. I'm using the laravel framework.

Comment: this could be done with angular.js define arrays with directives, then make it to a json obj since it will tunr into a stdclass it easily can be maintained in laravel using modules whichever youre using for your database. and the html form could be handled by angie using a scope containing an array. and the add more button, do it with javascript by adding new dom elements. hope its somewhat a way for you how it could be done. also, can you provide us the code of your html form?

Comment: You can also do it with react, jquery, vue, vanilla JS, etc. This doesn't need to be tied to any 1 library.

Comment: I updated my question with my html and j code, need some suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by using the position of the input in the parent as the index in the array, then saving the value in the array every time each input is changed. Then you can just add and remove inputs.

Sample code:

```
var offices = document.getElementById('offices');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var data = [];
var i = 0;

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Office');
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var index = i++;
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < offices.children.length; i++) {
      var child = offices.children[i];
      if (child === input) {
        break;
      }
    }
    // i is now the index in the array
    data[i] = input.value;
    renderText();
  });
  offices.appendChild(input);
});

document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var children = offices.children;
  if (children.length === data.length) {
    data = data.splice(0, data.length - 1);
  }
  offices.removeChild(children[children.length - 1]);
  renderText();
});

function renderText() {
  output.innerHTML = data.join(', ');
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/94sns39b/2/